# Prove that the addition map is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V be a vector space, Ok to prove that a map is linear (I unserstand a map as a function, its a synonym for me, please correct that if im wrong), all you have to do is two things:

-)$(f+g)(s) = f(s) + g(s)$ 
-)$kf(s)= f(ks)$

But the addition map is something of the form $V\times V \to V$

so i'm assuming the function here is something like this $f(v_i,v_j)=v_i+v_j$

But then it seems pretty stratighforward as an element $s$ would be $v_i,v_j$ and then its just a matter of plugging it into the above bullets and routine math. Is that really all?

Comment: Thank you @MoebiusCorzer, for the edit

Comment: To prove that a map $\varphi:V\to V:v\mapsto\varphi(v)$ is linear, you have to check that for any $v,w\in V$ and any $k\in\mathbb{F}$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field over which the vector space is defined), we have $\varphi(v+w)=\varphi(v)+\varphi(w)$ and $\varphi(kv)=k\varphi(v)$. EDIT: if you are working in the setup of vector spaces, it is a consequence of the definition that the addition map is bilinear.

Comment: If your understanding of the question is correct and f(v,w) = v + w you just have to show f(v,w) + f(y, z) = f(v+y, w+z) and f(k(v,w)) = kf(v,w).  Actually your statment $(f + g)(s) = f(s) + g(s)$ doesn't seem right to me.  That's always true by definition, isn't it?  I think you meant f(s + t) = f(s) + f(t).  Unless I misunderstand what you meant...

Comment: Actually @fleablood, i meant what you wrote there. I was working with sets of functions before and got confused, thank you.